# Computer isn't booting from disc

Tags: windows-8

I got a windows 8 laptop. It came pre-installed with it so it has the UFEI BIOS and whatnot.

I can get to the advanced recovery screen by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking the off button.

I chose to restart from my disc (which is in the computer, and works on other computers) and my computer restarts. After a few seconds my windows 8 login screen comes up.

I'm trying to boot to the windows 8 disc.

I haven't put windows 8.1 on it yet

Comment: Have you checked the boot order in your BIOS? DVD will need to be before HDD. What make is the laptop? I ran into an issue with a Samsung laptop and was unable to get it to boot from anything other than HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laptops that come preinstalled with Windows 8 have UEFI boot. IN most cases (as with me) you can't boot to DVD or a CD in UEFI bot. To boot to your Windows 8 disk, follow the steps below:

1. Insert your Windows 8 DVD and create an ISO. (you can use any tool. just google about ISO image tools). Try this one http://sourceforge.net/projects/iso-creator-cs/
2. Your Windows 8 ISO is created. Now download 'Rufus' from here : http://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus_v1.3.4.exe
3. Insert a USB stick (must be at least 4 GB). Open Rufus, select your device, under partition scheme and target type system select 'GPT Partition scheme for UEFI computer'. Select your ISO image (click on the small cd drive image). Click Start.
4. When done restart your computer and press the boot menu button (refer to your manufacturer guide). UEFI USB option will be available. Highlight on it and press enter.

Voila you are on your Windows 8 setup!!!

Answer (score 1):

What is on the disk that you are trying to boot to? Also, what make is your laptop?

As a generic answer that works most of the time:

1. Switch on computer and boot normally.
2. If you have no password on your account, log out (ensure no user is logged in)
3. Hit the power icon to reveal "Sleep/Restart/Shutdown"
4. Hold down a shift button and while its held down choose "Restart" with the mouse.
5. Release the shift key when a blue screen with choices appears.
6. Choose "Turn Off PC" from here.

What this is doing is a complete shut down of your PC rather than a standard "hybrid" sleep.

When your computer is switched back on, you will be able to choose which boot device to use. This will work in most situations, but if not, will need to know what you are trying to boot up and what make /model your machine is.